# script/rails vs rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing a tutorial where I demo some rails commands.  On my machine `rails` and `script/rails` both work equally well.  Is there a "preferred" form?  Which of the two works more universally?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you run the `rails` executable within a Rails 3 application, it looks for the `script/rails` file and, if it's present, executes that file with the arguments you passed to `rails`.

The reason why you'd use `rails` over `script/rails` generally falls down to the fact that it's shorter.

One more thing to note, there's also the `rails c` command which, in a Rails 2 application, will generate an application folder called `c` inside the current directory. Using `script/rails`, this wouldn't happen; instead it would complain that the `script/rails` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 14):

In Rails 3 it should be just rails.

Answer (score 5):

"rails" will show all about the script usage:

```
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate"
 benchmarker  See how fast a piece of code runs
 profiler     Get profile information from a piece of code
 plugin       Install a plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment

All commands can be run with -h for more information.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bundler, it is actually safer to say

```
bundle exec rails
```

as then you are assured of running the version of rails that is in your application's bundle. The same could be said for

```
bundle exec rake
```

Comment: rails already runs within the bundled gems if there's a Gemfile around.

Answer (score 2):

In window console we have to write ruby script/server
but on Ubuntu script/server is enough

rails s and rails c for rail3

Answer (score 1):

You should write just Rails not because is preferred, but just because it's going to become the standard, from here on.
script/rails was used in the previous version of rails and it is deprecated right now.

However both command have the same effects in this moment, there is nothing you can't do using rails instead script/rails

Answer (score 1):

`script/rails` is accessible only in the project application folder. Specifically using this would interrupt the OS's attempt to locate `rails` from the environment path and may raise an error (as it did on my PC). To create a new Rails App, `script/rails` won't work but `rails` would. I suggest you stick to the `rails` command.

Other commands such as `script/generate`, `script/server`, `script/console` have all become arguments of the `rails` call.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 it should be

```
rails
```

...

Comment: No, there is no `script/rails` within older versions of Rails.

Comment: For rails 2 it's script/server. I also place a nuch of aliases in my .bashrc for all the rails 2 and 3 commands e.g.

Answer (score 0):

`rails s` or `rails g scaffold` look for `script/rails` and just pass your arguments in.  `rails` is generally prefered because it's shorter and quicker to type.  However, if someone tries to use `rails s` or `rails c` in a rails 2.X app it'll add another application folder of that name since the rails command in 2.X generates an application.

If your demo is designed to run on Rails 3 only use `rails ...` if it's for more general make sure to mention the rails 2 uses `script/server ...` not `rails ...`

Answer (score 0):

`script/rails` commands are for Rails 2. Rails 3 uses `rails`. `script/` commands don't work on my installation.

Answer (score -5):

rails community is giving away much options to make the life easier of devs. The command rails do the same thing and is being used by lots of devs. Due to same reason rails is very popular.

Comment: The question is asking if there is a preferred form.